# I want to false autoComplete for all form in ExtJS 2.3

Tags: extjs, extjs2

I need help in `ExtJS 2.3`. I am unable to get success for `autoComplete = false`.

I want to false autoComplete for all form in `ExtJS 2.3`.

---

```
this.tabs.rateQuoteTab.on('render', function (cmp) {
    if (cmp && cmp.el && cmp.el.dom) {
        cmp.el.dom.autocomplete = 'off';
    }
})
```

[image: Here an screenshot of the rendered code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, before you post question, Please read [about Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you without example but please, if this don't help you, give me exemple of you'r code.

So, if you really want to set false autoComplete of ALL YOU'R FORMS you can override the class.

Here is link to the override method of ExtJS 2 : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext-method-override

But i think is not a good idea. ExtJS is OOP so you just have to create a new xtype extend formpanel and this new xtype have the autoComplete automaticaly false.

Have a nice day.

Comment: +  this.tabs.rateQuoteTab.on('render', function (cmp) {
+   if (cmp && cmp.el && cmp.el.dom) {
+    cmp.el.dom.autocomplete = 'off';
+   }
+  })

Comment: I tried with this code.   +  this.tabs.rateQuoteTab.on('render', function (cmp) {
+   if (cmp && cmp.el && cmp.el.dom) {
+    cmp.el.dom.autocomplete = 'off';
+   }
+  })